# User Authentication with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, express, passport.js

I'm making a User Authentication with passport. First I created a default Admin User. Now this Admin must able to create users but not any other users. For this I created a Admin user in Database. Now my Question is how to create the other users by the Admin and as well only this Admin should have access to all API's routes but not for any other Users how to protect the API's? In server.js file i created middleware function as

```
//Catch unauthorized errors
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    if(err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
        res.status(401);
        res.json({"message": err.name + ":" + err.message});
    }
});
```

Please help with this. I hope you guys don't mind for posting such a long files.

'authentication.js'

```
'use strict';
var passport = require('passport'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Users = mongoose.model('Users');


var authentication = {

    register: function(req, res, name, email, password) {
        var userData = req.body;

        var user = new Users({
            email: userData.email,
            name: userData.name,
        });

        user.setPassword(userData.password);

        if(!user) {
            res.status(400).send({error: 'All fields required'});
        }

        user.save(function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('Could not save the User');
                res.status(500).send({error: 'Could not save the User'});
            }else {
                res.send('New User Created Successfully');
            }
        });
    },

    login: function (req, res) {
        if(!req.body.email || !req.body.password) { 
            res.status(400).send({"message": "All fields required"});
            return;    
        }

        passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) { 
            var token;

            if (err) { 
        res.status(404).send({err: 'An Error Occured'});
                return;
            }

            if(user) { 
                token = user.generateJwt();
        res.status(300).send({"token": token});
            }else { 
        res.status(401).send('Unauthorized User');
            }
        });
    }

};

module.exports = authentication;
```

'user-model.js'

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    crypto = require('crypto'),
    jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: { 
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    name: { 
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    hash: String, 
    salt: String
});



userSchema.methods.setPassword = function (password) {
    this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex'); 
    this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex'); 
};

//Validating a submitted password
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function (password) {
    var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
    return this.hash === hash;
};

//Generating a JSON Web Token
userSchema.methods.generateJwt = function () {
    var expiry = new Date();
    expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() + 7);

    return jwt.sign({ 
        _id: this._id,
        email: this.email, 
        name: this.name,   
        exp: parseInt(expiry.getTime() / 1000) 
    }, process.env.JWT_SECRET); 
};

var User = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);
var user = new User();
user.name = 'Arjun Kumar';
user.email = 'arjun@kumar.com';
user.setPassword('myPassword');
user.save();
```

'user-route.js'

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express'),
    userRoute = express.Router(),
    jwt = require('express-jwt'),
    authentication = require('../controllers/authentication');

var auth = jwt({
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    userProperty: 'payload'
});

userRoute.post('/:adminuserid/register', auth, authentication.register)
    .post('/login', authentication.login);

module.exports = userRoute;
```

'passport.js'

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Users = mongoose.model('Users');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email'}, function (username, password, done) {
    Users.findOne({ email: username }, function (err, user) { 
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {                    
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'Incorrect username.'
            })
        }
        if (!user.validPassword(password)) { 
            return done(null, false, {      
                message: 'Incorrect password.'
            });
        }
        return done(null, user);
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do it to put all your functions in a conditional like this to give access only to admin:

```
 If(req.user.email === your admin email) {

Your function 

}
```

This should go under the routes that you want only the admin have access to.

Or if you have several admins , then you should alter your schema a bit and add an `admin : Number` which you can later declare for example any user with `admin:1` are system administrators otherwise not .

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Good luck

Comment: Amirani, thank you for your response. can you say me where do I need to put this condition?

Comment: If you're using express, then just use it when creating an admin route.